# pip ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'

Tags: python, pip, fedora

There appear to be conflicting libraries of python that pip is trying to access, as you can see with the following error:

```
[root@fedora user]# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import _tokenizer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_tokenizer.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ._trie import Trie
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .py import Trie as PyTrie
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/py.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._base import Trie as ABCTrie
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/_base.py", line 3, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib64/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

How can I fix this to be able to use pip? I have already tried
`dnf reinstall python` and `dnf reinstall python3` and `dnf remove python3-pip, dnf install python3-pip`.

Comment: Probably a duplicate, can you search existing Q&A on /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip or /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip ? Did you try to repro this in another virtual environment or build? What is the equivalent pip --option to manually deleting? etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by removing all pip folders in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

Open the File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/_base.py", and at line 3 instead of

```
from collections import Mapping
```

add .abc after collections

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```